# Get rid of atom linter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for some time but I paired with someone and I think he put a linter of some sort on my editor now I want to get it off because it is quite in the way. Here is a picture of it.
[image]

I don't even know which one it is? Any idea on how I can disable it?

Comment: Is it not listed in the preferences > plugins page of atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that does look annoying. In atom's settings page you can find a list of plugins and uninstall them.